# Cannot pass dictionary to function in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

Tearing my hair out on this one.

I'm trying to pass a dictionary of type [String:UIView] to a function in swift that's expecting a [NSObject:AnyObject] :

[image]

NOTE: I get the exact same error if I use NSString instead of String:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

opponentImageView is a UIImageView....

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**

turns out the issue was actually with the 'options' argument being passed 0.  Passing NSLayoutFormatOptions(0) made this misleading error go away.  Here is what the code now looks like:

[image]

It builds fine now...

Comment: The error message says that a Swift string is not a NSObject, which seems reasonable.

Comment: I get the same error for NSString - see above.  NSString inherits from NSObject so I'd expect the above to be ok, and in swift String can be used anywhere an NSString can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problem when you try to cast `String` as `NSObject` implicitly in pure swift class. You need to define it explicitly

```
let viewsDict:[NSObject:AnyObject] = ["yourview":view]
```

and there is one error more `options` can not be `0`.So define `options` as proper `NSLayoutFormatOptions` type.

Comment: Wow-  bizarre - turned out that the problem was actually the NSLayoutFormatOptions being passed a 0 rather than NSLayoutFormatOptions(0).  The error seemed to suggest the problem was with the dictionary.  Swift error handling is still rather poor :/

Comment: @Pinxaton Do file a bug report. Apple needs to hear about these unhelpful error messages.